# Maximum update depth exceeded in React error

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-props

So I was trying to send some props from child to parent and got this error. I am trying to send a callback function from child to parent and call that function in the child component. I have used this before but this time I got this error.

Here is my Parent Component.

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';

import SideDrawer from './SideDrawer';

class Header extends React.Component {

    state={
        drawerOpen:false
    }

    toggleDrawer = (value)=>{
        this.setState({
            drawerOpen: value
        });
    }


    render(){
        return(

              <AppBar>

                    <SideDrawer
                         open={this.state.drawerOpen}
                         onClose={this.toggleDrawer}
                       />    

              </AppBar>

        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Here is the child component

```
import React from 'react';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';


const SideDrawer = (props) => {
    return (
       <Drawer
         anchor="right"
         open={props.open}
         onClose={props.onClose(false)}
       >

       </Drawer>
    );
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because you are triggering a continuous update thing.

Your `<Drawer />` component directly fires the `onClose` prop. To prevent this, you can write the component as followed :

```
<Drawer
   anchor="right"
   open={props.open}
   onClose={() => props.onClose(false)}
>
</Drawer>
```

This way it will only be triggered `onClose`

To have a full loop detail, here it is :

- Drawer is rendered, onClose is triggered.
- onClose updated the drawerOpen value
- State has updated, re-render `SideDrawer` because it uses the `drawerOpen` value from state
- Drawer is rendered, onClose is triggered.
- And the loop starts again, kind of infinitely